# Blazor routing fails in Azure DevOps iframe

Tags: azure-devops, widget, vsix, blazor

I have a simple [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/client) website ([source code](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BlazorVsixStackOverflowQuestion)) which has a routing issue when running in an iframe on [Azure Devops](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/devops/) but not elsewhere.

The application works fine when running under the following conditions

- locally on my PC using Visual Studio (VS2019) using 'F5'
- locally as a static site after having published the project to disc using the Visual Studio 'Publish' function
- locally as a static site within an iframe of another unrelated site
- remotely as a hosted static site after uploading the published site to a host
- remotely as a static site within an iframe of another unrelated site (this second static site mimics AzureDevOps boards, using a different host name)

However when I generate an [Azure Devops widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops) and upload it to the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.BlazorWidget) Blazor routing fails and therefore the site fails to load correctly, as per this screenshot.

[image: ](Screenshot.PNG)[![dashboard screen shot]

The source code for the site (which nothing more than a simplified version of the default VS Blazor template) can be found [here](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BlazorVsixStackOverflowQuestion).

Observations

- all the blazor-related assets (i.e. Blazor & mono javascript files & various DLL files) are served up to the browser successfully
- the blazor DLL runs successfully (i.e. `Programs.cs` kicks in successfully - `Console.WriteLine` statements in `Program.cs` and `StartUp.cs` prove this)
- blazor fails to successfully find the default route and hence the `<NotFoundContent>` (defined in  `App.razor`) tag is displayed within the [Azure Devops iframe](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.BlazorWidget)

Things I have tried to solve the issue

- define the `base href` as "/" in `wwwroot\index.html`
- define the `base href` as "/dist" in `wwwroot\index.html`
- define the route in an `index.cs` file using a `[Route]` attribute
- dynamic define the `base href` in `wwwroot\index.html` at runtime using javascript (this caters for any changes to the iframe parent URL by Microsoft)

Notes

- all [Azure Devops widgets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Boards&sortBy=Downloads) run inside an iframe within [Azure Devops](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/devops/).
- the vsix file that was uploaded to Visual Studio Marketplace [can be found here](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BlazorVsixStackOverflowQuestion/blob/master/Src/BlazorVsixStackOverflowQuestion/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/publish/GregTrevellick.BlazorWidget-1.0.11.vsix).

Comment: Can't you find out which URL your app is receiving?  It is running.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you mean the iframe's parent URL - I identify that URL dynamically using javascript (see [code here](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BlazorVsixStackOverflowQuestion/blob/master/Src/BlazorVsixStackOverflowQuestion/wwwroot/index.html)). But the issue only occurs in Azure DevOps - when using a different site for the iframe parent my app works totally fine.

Comment: I've noticed that you are writing your `base href` after the content has loaded, when the `base href` should be part of the `head` section? Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Jamie Pretty sure setting the ```base href``` in the ```body``` makes no difference (surprisingly). when I set the ```base href``` in the ```body``` to a wrong value such as 'foobar' the assets fail to download, but when set to the correct value the assets do download. Even setting the ```base href``` in the ```head``` to what I am convinced is the correct value fails :-(

Comment: I have additionally raised this with the Azure Devops team [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/665775/blazor-routing-fails-in-azure-devops-iframe.html), as it seems more Azure Devops centric than Blazor centric at this time.

Answer (score 2):

The fix ultimately was related to, unsurprisingly, invalid routing.

Essentially one needs to redirect the user to the Blazor page itself using the `NavigationManager` as per the example below in `app.razor`, where the target razor page contains

```
@page "/mypage"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@{navigationManager.NavigateTo(@navigationManager.Uri.Replace("index.html", "") + "mypage");}

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Index)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

A full example can be seen in the branch `feature/StackOverflowFix` [here](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/BlazorVsixStackOverflowQuestion) which has now been published to the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.BlazorWidget).

Comment: Note that the above code fixes the navigation issue and the widget loads successfully but the widget itself does not work. Making it work is beyond the scope of the question and is not of concern to me.